# Database for filtering XML documents

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, redis, amazon-dynamodb, database

I would like to hear some suggestion on implementing database solution for below problem

```
1) There are 100 million XML documents saved to the database per
day. 

2) The database hold maximum 3 days of data

3) 1 million query request per day

4) The value through which the documents are filtered are stored in
a seperate table and mapped with the corresponding XMl document ID.

5) The documents are requested based on date range, documents
matching a list of ID's, Top 10 new documents, records that are new
after the previous request
```

Here is what I have done so far

```
1) Checked if I can use Redis, it is limited to few datatypes and
also cannot use multiple where conditions to filter the Hash in
Redis. Indexing based on date and lots of there fields. I am unable
to choose a right datastructure to store it on a hash

2) Investigated DynamoDB, its again a key vaue store where all the
filter conditions should be stored as one value. I am not sure if it
will be efficient querying a json document to filter the right XML
documnent.

3) Investigated Cassandra and it looks like it may fit my
requirement but it has a limitation saying that the read operations
might be slow. Cassandra has an advantage of faster write operation
over changing data. This looks like the best possible solition used
so far.
```

Currently we are using SQL server and there is a performance problem and so looking for a better solution.

Please suggest, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that reads in Cassandra might be slow, but it's hard to guarantee SLA for reads (usually they will be fast, but then, some of them slow).

Cassandra doesn't have search capabilities which you may need in the future (ordering, searching by many fields, ranked searching). You can probably achieve that with Cassandra, but with obviously greater amount of effort than with a database suited for searching operations.

I suggest you looking at [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/)/[Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). Let me quote the features of Lucene from their main website:

**Scalable**

- High-Performance Indexing
- over 150GB/hour on modern hardware
- small RAM requirements -- only 1MB heap
- incremental indexing as fast as batch indexing
- index size roughly 20-30% the size of text indexed

**Powerful, Accurate and Efficient Search Algorithms**

- ranked searching -- best results returned first
- many powerful query types: phrase queries, wildcard queries, proximity queries, range queries and more
- fielded searching (e.g. title, author, contents)
- sorting by any field
- multiple-index searching with merged results
- allows simultaneous update and searching
- flexible faceting, highlighting, joins and result grouping
- fast, memory-efficient and typo-tolerant suggesters
- pluggable ranking models, including the Vector Space Model and Okapi BM25
- configurable storage engine (codecs)